# Internal build system error на всех проектах Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, build-error

Я запуллила изменения с гита (с Fork если точнее) и теперь при открытии любого (даже нового) проекта возвращаются следующие ошибки (при разных запусках одного проекта ошибки разные):

```
Internal build system error. Backend exited with code 2
[  0/950    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1900b0aEDbg.dag/UnityEditor.UI.rsp
[  0/950    0s] WriteText Library/Bee/artifacts/1900b0aEDbg.dag/Unity.Burst.AdditionalFile.txt
...
```

или

```
internal build system error. backend exited with code -1073741819
```

При этом иногда в консоль выводятся отсутствующие символы:
[image]

Я уже перепробовала почти все, ничего из этого не помогло:

- Удаляла папку Bee
- Открывала проект в другой версии Unity
- Переустанавливала Unity Editor и Unity Hub
- ПК перезапускала
- Меняла настройки compatibility levels в Project Setting
- Ни одна из папок в дереве с Unity не имеет кириллицы в названии

Причем ни один тред по этому багу не дает какого-то конкретного решения. Уже начиню отчаиваться понемногу - второй день только и делаю что пытаюсь пофиксить эту проблему.

Comment: Изменения чего запуллила с гита?

Comment: Начтите с расшифровки тех загадочных сообщений. Попробуйте поменять язык системы на английский, или найти способ запустить сборку из командной строки.